# how to use roles - Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity

Tags: wcf

I have managed to get windows authentication working with a service call using this .config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>

      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Unsecured">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>

        <binding name="Secured">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="WebApplication.SecureService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Secured" contract="WebApplication.ISecureService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

In the service I'm able to see who is logged in using:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity;
```

I'd like to check the user is a member of a particular role, so I have tried enabling the `roleManager` thusly:

```
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Then checking the role using `Roles`

```
Roles.IsUserInRole(@"DOMANIN\Role");
or:
var id = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity;
Roles.IsUserInRole(id.Name, @"DOMANIN\Role");
```

But both throw exception:

"Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity."

Also if there is an attribute to check roles, that would be ideal as it would throw the right exception rather than me handling it myself.

**Update**

I just tried this:

```
if (Roles.RoleExists(@"DOMANIN\Role"))
```

and got a different exception:

"The configured Role Provider (WindowsTokenRoleProvider) relies upon Windows authentication to determine the groups that the user is allowed to be a member of. ASP.NET Role Manager cannot be used to manage Windows users and groups. Please use the SQLRoleProvider if you would like to support custom user/role assignment." Which I will Google, just thought it might help anyone who's looking at this for me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"DOMAIN\Role")]
public string DoWork()
{
    //user is authenticated and in the role
}
```

Still would be interested if any one can shed light on the exceptions.

This works even with out the `roleManager` enabled so clearly a different mechanism at work.

Answer (score 1):

The exceptions are telling you that you can only check the Role of the currently logged in User. To get a list of those in String form, this should work for you:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser()
```

But, you cannot get the Roles for some arbitrary user like you can when using Forms authentication.

Comment: Thanks Erix, note I did also try `Roles.IsUserInRole(@"DOMANIN\Role");` which works on the current logged in user, and got same message. I have tried what you suggested and got the same exception: "Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity."

Comment: @Weston Why do you have Authentication mode = "Forms".

Comment: It was just there by default, I also tried `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`